# Pathauto: Bulk update not working

Tags: path-aliases

Pathauto was working for me in the past but just now, after setting a new pattern for my content clicking bulk update while checking every single content type to be sure, I get the "No new URL aliases to generate" message.

I even tried changing the pattern of my other content that already has generated url aliases and ran bulk update later, but I still got the "No new URL aliases to generate" message.

How can I debug this problem? My pattern is straightforward:

```
blogs/[node:title]
```

Devel shows that the [node:title] token exists.

Comment: Have you deleted your exisiting aliases?

Comment: Thanks! I deleted them and it worked. However, I didn't need to delete my existing aliases in the past because bulk update will delete them automatically for me.

Comment: I'm using Path auto 7.x-1.2

Comment: Updating it from the admin/content page works as normal. I guess that I've forgotten what I did last time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating it from the admin/content page works as normal. I select what needs to be updated and scroll to the bottom to "Bulk operations -> Update URL alias".

I don't need to delete any URL aliases manually

Comment: I don't see that as an option in the dropdown. Do I have to enable something first to get the Update URL Alias option?